# Core Foundation memory leaks

Tags: memory-leaks, core-text, core-foundation

```
+ (CFArrayRef)getLinesForText:(NSAttributedString *)text width:(CGFloat)width {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 10000)];
    CTFramesetterRef frameSetterRef = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)text);
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetterRef, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path.CGPath, nil);
    CFArrayRef lines = CFArrayCreateCopy(NULL, CTFrameGetLines(frameRef));
    CFRelease(frameRef);
    CFRelease(frameSetterRef);
    return lines;
}
```

When using CoreText ， I have some code like this. After called the method , I use CFRelease to release the returned lines . But when profile with leaks ， these codes still have leaks ？How can this happened ？

Answer (score 0):

It is my fault. I need use CFAutorelease when the method returns, rather than let the caller release  the returned lines.